Which journals require BibTeX instead of BibLaTeX/biber in 2024?
Most of what I’m seeing is a decade or more of age and I’m curious what the current state is for journals in 2024. Are most journals accepting BibLaTeX/biber or is it still a minority situation?

You seem to assume there are any taking biblatex other than 'because they only really use a PDF' - I suspect that actual TeX-based workflows in journals do not allow for biblatex at all.

One major issue is that most publishers using TeX want the bibliography as a stand-alone paste-in element and that's not how biblatex works - the .bbl it produces is more like a data-source than a formatted bibliography and is not at all stand-alone as it contains macros specific to biblatex. There have been musing about how to deal with this but it's not a trivial issue to solve.

@PLK I was seeing that there is a way to have bibLaTeX generate a pasteable bbl. I would imagine that journals publishing in languages other than English would likely prefer BibLaTeX/biber if only for the Unicode and language-dependent sorting support.

I assume you mean 'most journals which accept .tex files at all' because the vast majority of journals do not take .tex so it makes no odds whether you use bibtex or biblatex/biber.

An analogous question comes to my mind: which journals require LaTeX instead of OpTeX na 2024? Answer: alas, all of them.
